# How to record two microphones?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone, jack

I am trying to record a usb headset's microphone and the monitor output to that headset, so far trying to open two recordings at the same time did not work (through python or Audacity), [this comment](https://portaudio.music.columbia.narkive.com/fzP6pZ3l/portaudio-error-9993-illegal-combination-of-i-o-devices#post2) has me believing that non of my portaudio based libraries will be able to record two things at the same time.

I have seen multiple mentions that I can use jack or pactl to create a combined source, I have tried using pactl to create a combined audio source, this did not work and required a manual step of choosing the input in the pulse audio GUI which I would have wanted to be automatic.

```
    pactl load-module module-null-sink sink_name=MySink
    pactl load-module module-loopback sink=MySink
    pactl load-module module-loopback sink=MySink
```

Finally I tried using jack but whatever device I'm trying to open using `alsa_in` I'm getting errors.

```
annot connect to server socket err = Connection refused
Cannot connect to server request channel
jackdmp 1.9.12
Copyright 2001-2005 Paul Davis and others.
Copyright 2004-2016 Grame.
Copyright 2016-2017 Filipe Coelho.
jackdmp comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY
This is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it
under certain conditions; see the file COPYING for details
Cannot create RT messagebuffer thread: Operation not permitted (1)
Retrying messagebuffer thread without RT scheduling
Messagebuffer not realtime; consider enabling RT scheduling for user
no message buffer overruns
Cannot create RT messagebuffer thread: Operation not permitted (1)
Retrying messagebuffer thread without RT scheduling
Messagebuffer not realtime; consider enabling RT scheduling for user
no message buffer overruns
Cannot create RT messagebuffer thread: Operation not permitted (1)
Retrying messagebuffer thread without RT scheduling
Messagebuffer not realtime; consider enabling RT scheduling for user
no message buffer overruns
JACK server starting in realtime mode with priority 10
self-connect-mode is "Don't restrict self connect requests"
Cannot lock down 82280346 byte memory area (Cannot allocate memory)
audio_reservation_init
Acquire audio card Audio0
creating alsa driver ... hw:0|hw:0|1024|2|44100|0|0|nomon|swmeter|-|32bit
configuring for 44100Hz, period = 1024 frames (23.2 ms), buffer = 2 periods
ALSA: final selected sample format for capture: 32bit integer little-endian
ALSA: use 2 periods for capture
ALSA: final selected sample format for playback: 32bit integer little-endian
ALSA: use 2 periods for playback
Cannot use real-time scheduling (RR/10)(1: Operation not permitted)
AcquireSelfRealTime error
Cannot lock down 82280346 byte memory area (Cannot allocate memory)
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:990:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) The dmix plugin supports only playback stream
Capture open error: Invalid argument
Unknown error...                                                                                          
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Jack::JackTemporaryException'
  what():
```